# What Design Patterns are used on iOS other than MVC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, architecture

I need to know about the design patterns used in iPhone development other than MVC.

Please reply with any sample explanation or example with code snippet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

### [Abstract Factory](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW32)

The Abstract Factory pattern provides an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes. The client is decoupled from any of the specifics of the concrete object obtained from the factory.

### [Adapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW35)

The Adapter design pattern converts the interface of a class into another interface that clients expect. Adapter lets classes work together that couldn’t otherwise because of incompatible interfaces. It decouples the client from the class of the targeted object.

### [Chain of Responsibility](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW25)

The Chain of Responsibility design pattern decouples the sender of a request from its receiver by giving more than one object a chance to handle the request. The pattern chains the receiving objects together and passes the request along the chain until an object handles it. Each object in the chain either handles the request or passes it to the next object in the chain.

### [Command](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW14)

The Command design pattern encapsulates a request as an object, thereby letting you parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests, and support undoable operations. The request object binds together one or more actions on a specific receiver. The Command pattern separates an object making a request from the objects that receive and execute that request.

### [Composite](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW15)

The Composite design pattern composes related objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies. The pattern lets clients treat individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly. The Composite pattern is part of the Model-View-Controller aggregate pattern.

### [Decorator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW43)

The Decorator design pattern attaches additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality. As does subclassing, adaptation of the Decorator pattern allows you to incorporate new behavior without modifying existing code. Decorators wrap an object of the class whose behavior they extend. They implement the same interface as the object they wrap and add their own behavior either before or after delegating a task to the wrapped object. The Decorator pattern expresses the design principle that classes should be open to extension but closed to modification.

### [Facade](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW47)

The Facade design pattern provides a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem. The pattern defines a higher-level interface that makes the subsystem easier to use by reducing complexity and hiding the communication and dependencies between subsystems.

### [Iterator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW50)

The Iterator design pattern provides a way to access the elements of an aggregate object (that is, a collection) sequentially without exposing its underlying representation. The Iterator pattern transfers the responsibility for accessing and traversing the elements of a collection from the collection itself to an iterator object. The Iterator defines an interface for accessing collection elements and keeps track of the current element. Different iterators can carry out different traversal policies.

### [Mediator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW28)

The Mediator design pattern defines an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact. Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently. These objects can thus remain more reusable.
A "mediator object” in this pattern centralizes complex communication and control logic between objects in a system. These objects tell the mediator object when their state changes and, in turn, respond to requests from the mediator object.

### [Memento](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW54)

The Memento pattern captures and externalizes an object’s internal state—without violating encapsulation—so that the object can be restored to this state later. The Memento pattern keeps the important state of a key object external from that object to maintain cohesion.

### [Observer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW20)

The Observer design pattern defines a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically. The Observer pattern is essentially a publish-and-subscribe model in which the subject and its observers are loosely coupled. Communication can take place between the observing and observed objects without either needing to know much about the other.

### [Proxy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW17)

The Proxy design pattern provides a surrogate, or placeholder, for another object in order to control access to that other object. You use this pattern to create a representative, or proxy, object that controls access to another object, which may be remote, expensive to create, or in need of securing. This pattern is structurally similar to the Decorator pattern but it serves a different purpose; Decorator adds behavior to an object whereas Proxy controls access to an object.

### [Receptionist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW106)

The Receptionist design pattern addresses the general problem of redirecting an event occurring in one execution context of an application to another execution context for handling. It is a hybrid pattern. Although it doesn’t appear in the “Gang of Four” book, it combines elements of the Command, Memo, and Proxy design patterns described in that book. It is also a variant of the Trampoline pattern (which also doesn’t appear in the book); in this pattern, an event initially is received by a trampoline object, so-called because it immediately bounces, or redirects, the event to a target object for handling.

### [Singleton](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW66)

The Singleton design pattern ensures a class only has one instance, and provides a global point of access to it. The class keeps track of its sole instance and ensures that no other instance can be created. Singleton classes are appropriate for situations where it makes sense for a single object to provide access to a global resource.

### [Template Method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW26)

The Template Method design pattern defines the skeleton of an algorithm in an operation, deferring some steps to subclasses. The Template Method pattern lets subclasses redefine certain steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm’s structure.

**Source:** [Cocoa Design Patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW6).

Comment: Any reason why the linked document is in the retired documents library?

When I click on that link, it redirects me to this: "The Retired Documents Library contains documents that are not applicable for current product development. Some of these documents describe older programming techniques that are no longer recommended. Other documents describe older features, interfaces, and programming techniques that are no longer supported. This information is available to help you maintain and update older code bases."

Are they suggesting that these programming techniques are no longer recommended?

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer No. They probably just archived the whole documentation with the release of a new OS. The design patterns are still all valid, they don't just change like that.

Comment: The term cocoa design patterns are misleading, especially when all this contains is simple definition of pre-existing patterns. A real-world cocoa example of each pattern is expected of the 'retired document'.

Answer (score 2):

In real world applications code bases become complex over time and you end up with massive view controllers, which are hard to test and maintain. The solution is to use [MVVM](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/mvvm/), which is a better alternative to MVC it self.

Answer (score 1):

Using MVVM Design pattern in your application is related to your business logic that you will do in your project to display some contents on view.
Incase your view doesn't need more logic to display it's content you can use MVC
but if you have to make some business logic to display these contents on view the best practise in this case is to separate this logic to be in another layer so MVVM will better in this case,ViewModel in MVVM will contain this logic.

In my opinion MVVM is better than MVC on level design due to these reasons

- MVVM is compatible with your existing MVC architecture.
- MVVM makes your apps more testable.
- MVVM works best with a binding mechanism.

**How MVVM is compatible with MVC**

- MVC > Model,View,Controller
- MVVM > Model,View ,ViewModel > Model,(ViewController),ViewModel