# Foundation or UIKit example of composition

Tags: ios, composition

I'm trying to understand the design principle of composition better. Are there any examples of this in the UIKit or Foundation frameworks?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/

From my experience, and before thinking about this question explicitly, it seems that inheritance is the main pattern for these two frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance is rare in Foundation, and is not the primary pattern of UIKit. Composition is much more common in both cases.

The difference between inheritance and composition is often expressed as IS-A versus HAS-A. The IS-A approach to is to subclass. The HAS-A approach is to delegate.

Consider a text field that you would like to only accept certain characters. In an IS-A style, you would subclass `UITextField`. That's not common in iOS. Instead, you pass a delegate (anything that conforms to `<UITextFieldDelegate>`) and the text field consults it when needed. This is a HAS-A approach. A text field "has a" delegate.

Consider a `UITableView`. You would like to make a table of songs. In the IS-A (inheritance) approach, you would subclass `UITableView` and make a `SongsTableView`. In the HAS-A (composition) approach, you would create some other object (a `SongsDataSource`) and give it to a `UITableView`. In this case, UIKit uses a little of both; you give the `UITableView` a data source, but that data source is usually (but not required to be) a subclass of `UITableViewController`.

Similarly, while it is somewhat common to subclass `UIView` or `CALayer`, it is also very common to use "stock" views and layers instead and build them up by adding sub-components. This is the HAS-A approach.

Foundation has very little IS-A in it. You very seldom subclass Foundation classes other than `NSObject`. Consider `NSAttributedString`. It does not subclass `NSString`. It *has* an `NSString`. This is the usual way of doing things in Foundation. You almost never create your own subclasses of `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDate`, `NSNumber` or any of the other common types out of Foundation. You combine them instead.

Comment: So adding a property to another object is part of the composition pattern? ie. `@property (...) UITextField* loginTextField` added to a UIViewController is considered composition? If yes, I don't see the alternative way of doing this with inheritance. Or this is just an extreme example on the composition end of the spectrum?

Comment: Yes, properties are definitely examples of composition. It's very difficult to avoid composition in OOP. It's a fundamental part of the paradigm, even more than subclassing (prototype-based OOP like JavaScript doesn't even have subclassing). View controllers are one of the most complicated pieces of the system, with significant use of both composition and inheritance, so are likely the hardest to get a clear picture with. Start by thinking about simpler things like text fields. Consider how you might build a NumberOnlyTextField vs using a NumberOnlyTextFieldDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got your question wrong, but perhaps that's what you looking for:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW15

Here simular question on SO:

[What Design Patterns are used on iOS other than MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436497/what-design-patterns-are-used-on-ios-other-than-mvc)

And here's pretty good description of pattern that perhaps let you get know it better:

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite